# when using a custom namespace attribute in a library project, use the namespace "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" instead

Tags: android

I am trying to implement ijoomer advance in the android application. I am refering to the link :
https://www.ijoomer.com/iJoomer-Advance/developer-manual.html

I have imported the ijoomer advance sdk and facebook sdk in my workspace. I have included both as library too. But in "IjoomerAdvance1.3\res\layout\ijoomer_loading_dialog.xml" I am getting follwing error:[image]

when I refer to the xml file I have following error:
[image]

When I use "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" the problem is solved but I have following error:

[image]

According to the above link, in manifest.xml file I have created activity tag with the java class from library file:

[image]

In my mainactivity.java file I have extended from smartApplication.
[image]

And included ijoomeradvace as library project.[image]

Can anyone help me with my problem?

Comment: Well have you tried what it says? `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` instead of what you have?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" />
```

According to android documentation:

> Added support for custom views with custom attributes in libraries. Layouts using custom attributes must use the namespace URI http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto instead of the URI that includes the app package name. This URI is replaced with the app specific one at build time

Comment: Please create a new question for the new problem.